# How can I dynamically resize a UITableViewCell based on the height of my label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView.

I am overriding the table row height, but I would like the first row to have a dynamic height that is based on the size of the height of the Label in my cell. How can I get this height?

```
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 0;

    if(indexPath.section == kBioSection) {
        switch(indexPath.row) {
            case kBioSectionDescriptionRow:                 
                rowHeight = 100;
                break;
            case kBioSectionLocationRow:                    
                rowHeight = 44;
                break;
            case kBioSectionWebsiteRow:                 
                rowHeight = 44;
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        rowHeight = 44;
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Does this work? If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: Also, I believe you can accomplish the above code with a single `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString has a method called

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

declared in `UIStringDrawing.h`

It will give you the size required to draw that string.

You can get the height of that required size, and add whatever else you want, like other labels/views, and space between them, to calculate the final height.

Something like this:

```
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 0;

    if(indexPath.section == kBioSection) {
        switch(indexPath.row) {
            case kBioSectionDescriptionRow:                 
                CGSize labelSize = [descriptionText sizeWithFont:labelFont forWidth:tableView.frame.size.width - 20 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; //Assuming 10 px on each side of the label
                rowHeight = labelSize + 50; //Assuming there are 50 px of extra space on the label, besides the text
                break;
            case kBioSectionLocationRow:                    
                rowHeight = 44;
                break;
            case kBioSectionWebsiteRow:                 
                rowHeight = 44;
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        rowHeight = 44;
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: My tableview seems to crash. I'm grabbing the cell's detailTextLabel, which I think might be causing the problem.

Comment: Why is it crashing? What are you grabbing the cell's detailTextLabel for?

Comment: because I want to resize the cell row height based on the detailTextLabel height.

Comment: I'm aware but you never need to grab the detailTextLabel, just the text you'll put in it (`descriptionText` is that in the code I wrote). labelSize will be the size the detailTextLabel will have. Also, what kind of crash are you having, and where exactly? It's easier for me to help if you provide as many details as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the below link:

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/ -- This tutorial clearly explains you how to increase UITableViewCell height dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
 {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
}
```

set height for cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText = @"Go get some text for your cell.";
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

return labelSize.height + 20;//set as per your need
}
```